# OMIM diseases to UMLS mapping

Tags: public-databases

Is there any public available mapping between Online Mendelian Inheritance in Man (OMIM) diseases and Unified Medical Language System (UMLS) concepts?

OMIM has mapping for genes to entrez or ensembl, but has no mapping for diseases? Does anything exists that would allow me to map OMIM diseases to UMLS?